# Hadamard product gradient

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I have a cost function as such:
$$ c = ||y-A(b:x)||_2^2 $$
Where $:$ denotes Hadamard product. I need to differentiate this with respect to $x$. What I come up with is as follows:
$$A = [\alpha_1 ... \alpha_N]$$
$$A(b:x) = [\alpha_1 ... \alpha_N][b_1x_1 ... b_Nx_N]^T=[\alpha_1b_1...\alpha_Nb_N][x_1...x_N]^T=Bx$$
where $$B=[\alpha_1b_1...\alpha_Nb_N]$$
Then I write cost function as
$$c = ||y-Bx||_2^2$$ which has a gradient of
$$2Re[B^H(Bx-y)]$$
However, results do not seem to be correct. Any ideas or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

The Hadamard product with a vector can be replaced by the regular matrix product with a diagonal matrix generated from the vector, i.e.
$$B={\rm Diag}(b) \quad\implies\quad (b:x) = Bx\qquad\quad$$
This converts your problem to a more standard form, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
c &= \big\|ABx-y\big\|^2_2 \\
}$$
In the *complex* case, one has the well-known Wirtinger gradients
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} &= (AB)^T(ABx-y)^* \\
\frac{\partial c}{\partial x^*} &= (AB)^H(ABx-y) \\}$$
and in the *real* case, the mundane gradient
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} &= 2(AB)^T(ABx-y) \\
}$$

Comment: Than you very much for your detailed answer. I understood until the conversion of the cost function to a more standard form. Up to that, the solutions seem to be parallel. However, what I wonder more is if the gradient expression I found is correct or not.